# firefox the html editor?

Tags: html, css, firefox, firefox-addon, firebug

There are a lot of [webdeveloper addons](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/collections/mozilla/webdeveloper/) available, for firefox, like [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/firebug/).

But is there a html editor addon for firefox. Which i can edit my website. viewing 
the edits real-time (using localhost or via ftp?) and saving the edits(`CTRL`-`S`)

i am currenlty using firebug and it would save a lot of time if i could save the
(local) `.html` file using a firebug like addon!(or firebug itself?)

---

i Found a [firebug addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firefile/) to save .css files... now just need one to save html, and i am good to go!

Answer (score 0):

Firefox 17 (Aurora) has a built-in editor https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/09/html-editing-and-other-improvements-in-firefox-17-developer-tools/

Comment: That's only for DOM manipulation.  There is nothing in that link about saving changes to the source file.